# Why can't I find the svg line of code in my html file

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, svg

So I wanted to add a morris chart to my laravel project and I'm using a template. My question is that when I look at my html code in sublime I can't find the svg line in it but when I look at it from my browser using "inspect"
I get multiple lines of code that I can't find in the html file.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: I would assume the svg is getting added dynamically by JavaScript?

Comment: that is because there is javascript working on the id ` morris-bar-chart `

Comment: Please include the actual code in the question instead of referring to images that might in the future break.

Comment: You can't find html code in your html file because everything is handled by javascript code/file. That javascript code/file append all html element after finished loading your page to that element id `morris-bar-chart`.
     
You can find that string `morris-bar-chart` in your javascript file/code then you can get that.

Answer (score 0):

Those `svg` create by `morris chart` you have `#morris-bar-chart` on based on that morris chart `init` and create those `svg` while rendering on browser.